# How to make Oracle SQL Developer show an application icon?

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, taskbar, application-icon

When running Oracle SQL Developer v21.2.1.204 on Windows 10 it only shows a generic "plain text" icon in the task bar, not the application icon. I have tried to assign the icon found in file `sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.exe` from the installation folder to the shortcut that starts SQL Developer but Windows still shows the generic application icon instead.

[image: Windows task bar icon for SQL Developer]

Is there a way to get Oracle SQL Developer to use its specific application icon for the Windows task bar?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the default behavior.

Shown: Windows 10, Java 11, SQL Developer 21.2.1.

[image]

Note: I don't have (and don't recommend) SQLDev running under Program Files.

I'm launching the app directly from Explorer -

[image]

Comment: The application is installed into `C:\Oracle\sqldeveloper` on my system, so outside of the Program Files folder which is managed by Windows. Still the task bar does not show the real application icon (database with green play symbol) on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting only the problematic .exe again from the "sqldeveloper/bin/" folder in the original RAR file. In my case was sqldeveloper64W.exe

[SQL Developer Executable Shortcut Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le9jO.png)

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).